# Is there a better way to deal with untextured regions in stereo matching

Tags: computer-vision, matching, stereo-3d

Texture is very helpful for stereo matching. However in real environment, untextured areas 
always exit. Consistent semi-global matching is proposed to deal with untextured regions. 
I start to read the paper ***Stereo Vision in Structured Environments by Consistent Semi-Global Matching.***
Fixed bandwidth Mean Shift segmentation is used.

If some have some experience with Consistent Semi-Global Matching,
I hope to learn whether the algorithm is good for untextured regions. How about the complexity of the algorithm?
Is there any better way to deal with untextured regions?

Comment: I'm no expert in stereo algorithms but if there is no texture you cannot find corresponding points so you cannot calculate depth information. no matter what algorithm you use. the only good solution to this problem is to create texture by structured illumination (assuming the surface is not too smooth)

Comment: It is expected that the information from textured regions can be propagated to untextured regions. Walls and floors are always untextured regions. Sky and roads are untextured regions outdoors.So some ways are needed to deal with untextured regions.

Comment: and how do you measure the distance to the sky? :) that's not even a surface. of course you can do some interpolations here and there but that's not stereo vision, thats guessing based on some assumptions and models.